# Algebra (inequalities)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $\{a,b\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Show that: 
>   $$a^2+b^2+ \frac{1}{a^2}+ \frac{b}{a} \geq \sqrt{3}$$

I am unable to apply AM-GM inequality in the given problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Root under 3" ? Do you mean $\sqrt{3}$ ?

Comment: yes,I mean sqrt(3).

Comment: Excuse me! I made a mistake in my calculation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$b^2+\frac{1}{a}\cdot{b}+a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}-\sqrt3\geq0,$$
for which we need $\Delta\leq0$ or
$$\frac{1}{a^2}-4\left(a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}-\sqrt3\right)\leq0$$ or
$$4a^2+\frac{3}{a^2}\geq4\sqrt3,$$ which is AM-GM:
$$4a^2+\frac{3}{a^2}\geq2\sqrt{4a^2\cdot\frac{3}{a^2}}=4\sqrt3.$$
Done!

Answer (score 4):

it is equivalent to
$$\left(ab+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(a^2-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

One could do as follows as well, if some calculus were allowed.

Consider the function $ f(a,b) = a^2 + b^2 + \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{b}{a}$. 
As we are looking for a lower bound, we could calculate $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = 2b + \frac{1}{a}$ and, upon setting to zero, look along the domain restriction $$ b = -\frac{1}{2a}$$ only.
Substituting yields the expression $$a^2 + \frac{3}{4a^2} = \frac{2a^2 + \frac{3}{2a^2}}{2} $$ after which we can apply the AM-GM inequality $$\frac {x+y}{2} \geq \sqrt {x y}$$ upon setting $x=2a^2$ and $y = \frac{3}{2a^2} $, concluding that the given expression is equal or greater than $$ \sqrt{  2a^2 \frac{3}{2a^2}} = \sqrt{3}$$